Error in QGIS when doing operations on raster data loaded from Postgres
I am trying to create a virtual raster in QGIS with raster data imported from a local Postgres database. I go Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster... and click Run. Here's the log with the command and the error:
    Algorithm 'Build virtual raster' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ADD_ALPHA' : False, 'ASSIGN_CRS' : None, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : ['postgresraster://dbname=\'raster_demo\' host=localhost port=5432 authcfg=2ef08t3 srid=32630 table="public"."b2" (rast)','postgresraster://dbname=\'raster_demo\' host=localhost port=5432 authcfg=2ef08t3 srid=32630 table="public"."b3" (rast)','postgresraster://dbname=\'raster_demo\' host=localhost port=5432 authcfg=2ef08t3 srid=32630 table="public"."b4" (rast)'], 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PROJ_DIFFERENCE' : False, 'RESAMPLING' : 0, 'RESOLUTION' : 1, 'SEPARATE' : False, 'SRC_NODATA' : '' }

GDAL command:
gdalbuildvrt -overwrite -resolution highest -r nearest -input_file_list C:/Users/aleja/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_RFHsgU/45122de51c4c484fba0d05fdd11764ad/buildvrtInputFiles.txt C:/Users/aleja/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_RFHsgU/105e8a62dc1e4457a6022f8417243f22/OUTPUT.vrt
GDAL command output:
Warning 1: Can't open dbname='raster_demo' host=localhost port=5432 authcfg=2ef08t3 srid=32630 table="public"."b2" (rast). Skipping it
Warning 1: Can't open dbname='raster_demo' host=localhost port=5432 authcfg=2ef08t3 srid=32630 table="public"."b3" (rast). Skipping it
Warning 1: Can't open dbname='raster_demo' host=localhost port=5432 authcfg=2ef08t3 srid=32630 table="public"."b4" (rast). Skipping it
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.10 seconds
Results:
  OUTPUT: C:/Users/aleja/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_RFHsgU/105e8a62dc1e4457a6022f8417243f22/OUTPUT.vrt

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/aleja/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_RFHsgU/105e8a62dc1e4457a6022f8417243f22/OUTPUT.vrt
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

I get a similar error when doing other operations on data. The same thing happens with the SCP plugin. For some reason, it can't find the database.
How can I do this?

I eventually found out what the problem was and how to solve it.
QGIS does not correctly create input file strings for raster data hosted on a PostgreSQL database. So, we need to edit the command and execute it on the OSGeo4W Shell. Copy the command shown in the GDAL/OGR console call. Now edit it. It should follow the rules shown here: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/postgisraster.html
We also need to edit the output file path. QGIS sets it to a temporary directory. Change it to your preferred path. It is a good idea to wrap the file path in “”. Now search OSGeo4W Shell in the Windows search bar and open it. Copy and paste the command into it. Press enter. Done! The newly created file should be in your chosen directory ready to be loaded into QGIS.
